# Display custom image on list.phtml

Tags: magento

I am trying to include a custom image attribute in list.phtml. 
The attribute is included in the product collection using the addAttribute method in catalog.xml:

```
<action method="addAttribute"><code>hover_image</code></action>
```

If I try $_product->getHoverImage, I get the url fine.
But when I try to resize the image using:

```
 $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'hover_image')->resize(240,186)
```

It doesn't work, I receive a error "Image file was not found."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get it to work with a simple if statement:

```
<?php if($_product->getHoverImage()): ?>
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product,'hover_image')->resize(240,186); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```